# AFOAuth2Client and refresh token

Tags: ios, ipad, oauth-2.0, afnetworking

How to implement the Oauth in iPad application?

How does AFOAuth2Client manages refreshing token mechanism in oauth 2.0?

Is there any method to implement it inside the class or do we have to implement it in our own way? How to check the token is expired or not?

Answer (score 11):

The way that I have solved this is to wrap all my requests with a code block which will refresh the access token if needed e.g.

Add some typedefs for success and failure blocks:

```
typedef void (^YFRailsSaasApiClientSuccess)(AFJSONRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject);
typedef void (^YFRailsSaasApiClientFailure)(AFJSONRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error);
```

Then the request method is:

```
- (void)getProductsWithSuccess:(YFRailsSaasApiClientSuccess)success failure:(YFRailsSaasApiClientFailure)failure {
    NSLog(@"getProductsWithSuccess");

    success = ^(AFJSONRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [self getPath:@"api/1/products"
           parameters:nil
              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                  NSLog(@"getProductsWithSuccess: success");

                  // TODO: handle response

                  if (success) {
                      success((AFJSONRequestOperation *)operation, responseObject);
                  }
              } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                  NSLog(@"getProductsWithSuccess: failure");
              if (failure) {
                  failure((AFJSONRequestOperation *)operation, error);
              }
          }];
    };

    [self refreshAccessTokenWithSuccess:success failure:failure];
}
```

And the method which checks for token expiry and refreshes it if needed is:

```
- (void)refreshAccessTokenWithSuccess:(YFRailsSaasApiClientSuccess)success failure:(YFRailsSaasApiClientFailure)failure {
    NSLog(@"refreshAccessTokenWithSuccess");

    if (self.credential == nil) {
        if (failure) {
            NSMutableDictionary *errorDetail = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [errorDetail setValue:@"Failed to get credentials" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
            NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"world" code:200 userInfo:errorDetail];
            failure(nil, error);
        }
        return;
    }  

    if (!self.credential.isExpired) {
        NSLog(@"refreshAccessTokenWithSuccess: credential has not expired");

        if (success) {
            success(nil, nil);
        }
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"refreshAccessTokenWithSuccess: refreshing credential");

    [self authenticateUsingOAuthWithPath:@"oauth/token"
                            refreshToken:self.credential.refreshToken
                                 success:^(AFOAuthCredential *newCredential) {
                                     NSLog(@"Successfully refreshed OAuth credentials %@", newCredential.accessToken);
                                     self.credential = newCredential;
                                     [AFOAuthCredential storeCredential:newCredential
                                                     withIdentifier:self.serviceProviderIdentifier];

                                     if (success) {
                                         success(nil, nil);
                                     }
                                 }
                                 failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                     NSLog(@"An error occurred refreshing credential: %@", error);
                                     if (failure) {
                                         failure(nil, error);
                                     }
                                 }];
}
```

Full source code is up on GitHub: https://github.com/yellowfeather/rails-saas-ios.

Comment: In addition, you could move the storing of the credential to the setter of the property.

Comment: It would appear that this is depending on expires_in on the token which assumes your clock is fairly closely in sync with the server, even after network lag (which may or may not be an issue) and that your server does indeed set the expires_in value properly. expires_in is recommended, but not required in the spec. This indicates that on servers that do not support expires_in, the refresh should be done after an error is received on a request with the token. Typical the error to trigger a refresh is a 401. Just wanted to note that while this solution may work, it may not always work.

Comment: @ptoinson You are right and I am running into this issue, do you have any code sample to share that performs a refresh and then send the request with the refreshed token? I am trying to observe AFNetworkingOperationDidFinishNotification but can't come up with a satisfying solution.

Comment: @Newcode: I created an AFHTTPClient-subclass that uses the delegate-pattern and an extended failure-block to fetch a new token: https://github.com/booiiing/AFAuthorizedClient Just tune the existing delegates to your needs or implement your own. Be aware that there are other (perhaps easier) possibilities to ensure proper credentials, including using operation-dependencies with a (small, fixed) request to a secured resource or hooking into the existing authentication-mechanism of AFNetworking. Depending on your server, those might or might not be preferable.

Comment: @Newcode:I've created code to work the issue. However, I have several layers on top of NSNetworking including RestKit. I pretty much just look for 401 responses, cache the request that generated the 401, refresh the token and retry the request that triggered the 401. It gets pretty complicated since I also can have requests going on in parallel and can get a 401 in any one of them. Don't really want to do a token refresh when one is already in progress. patric.schenke's code will get you most of the way there.